# Triangulating 3D polygon created using 3D curves

Tags: opengl, graphics, opengl-es, triangulation

I have 3 or more 3D curves that construct a non planar polygon. Basically the input here is a list of 3D points that construct a closed shape.

I am looking for a way to triangulate this shape so i could draw it using OpenGL with textures. What are the common algorithms and/or c++ libraries that i could use?

The following is an example of such surface created from 4 strokes (imagine it is in 3D):

[image]

Comment: Can your edit your question and post screenshots of examples of such curves, so that we can understand what you expect?

Comment: I added a screenshot of such surface

Comment: just curious, have you found an answer to this question ?